# What's a word for someone with an attitude of smug cruelty?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who derives a feeling of glee from the success of intentionally hurting someone, and getting away with it.

The closest I can articulate this is as the attitude of someone who exhibits [duper's delight](http://www.changingminds.org/explanations/behaviors/lying/dupers_delight.htm).

> "Duper's delight" is the delight that people feel when they deceive others.

But "duper's delight" is a phrase and not a word, describes a feeling and not a person, and doesn't have the element of cruelty.

The word I'm looking for is close to sadistic, but with a smug, gleeful attitude and childish impudence to it.

Comment: Like ***cruel***?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the downvote?

Comment: **Feindish** seems close.

Comment: Unless I missed something vital, not a word in the detail has anything to do with any *attitude of smug cruelty*. Did I miss something there, or what, please?

*Duper's delight* is all about deceit, isn’t it? What has *deceit* to do with either smugness or cruelty?

I don’t go in for that kind of fun but doesn’t sadistic include a smug, gleeful attitude?

Answer (score 0):

**[Schadenfreude](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/schadenfreude)**

> Pleasure derived by someone from another person's misfortune.

Comment: Schadenfreude is a great word; but it doesn't suggest that the person enjoying the misfortune caused it.  Not like a practical joker who thinks it's funny that he caused you to fall and hurt yourself.

Comment: @Xanne Right you are. It's quite hard to find an apropos word that fits all the conditions. Sadomasochism might suggest that one enjoys the pleasure of hurting others, but it also suggests that the one who causes the harm enjoys the reciprocal hurt as well—usually in a sexual context.